# Google Adsense are not visible

Tags: wordpress, adsense

i have placed the Google ad sense code on website.. it shows the block but Google ad is not visible.
Looking forward for your valuable advise and experience.

Comment: Can you give us a link to the website please? It's hard to help you without any code or info.

Comment: check in your adsense account whether the inserted ad unit is active or not?

Comment: here is website link  https://nimzacollection.com

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here I have found what is causing this issue. When I insert the ad code inside the wordpress widgets, the wordpress is automatically removing the comments line of adsense > for eg:    this is name of the ad unit given by adsense in the form of comment. But when I checked the webpage source code, it is automatically removing this line and so ads are not appearing and empty blocks appear. Haven't found a solution yet, will post it if I find it. I came here searching for one and saw your post.

Comment: https://nimzacollection.com/  here is my website link.. i am clueless whats happening here.. code seems to be perfectly fine placed...